# How to use magic TypeScript or recursion?

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I have two methods:

```
public prop<K extends keyof ResponseInvitation.RootObject>(key: K) {
    return this._has(key) ? this.user[key] : null;
  }

  private _has(prop: string): boolean {
    return this.user.hasOwnProperty(prop);
  }
```

And I use this like:

```
let prop = this.prop('profile'); // Return object
```

Hot to call chain of `this.prop` in case when returned property is object:

```
 let prop = this.prop(this.prop('profile').organization);
```

Note above means that I try to get property by name `profile`. It returns object in which we have property `organization` as string.

I think I need this:

```
private _has(prop: string): boolean {
    let prop = this.user.hasOwnProperty(prop);

    if (typeof prop == 'object') {
       return this._has(prop);
    }
}
```

Regarding my issue I tried to rewrite a logic and got this working code:

```
interface RootObject { 
  name: string;
  organization: Org; 
}

interface Org { 
  name: string;
}

class A { 

  public user: any;
  public last: string;

public prop<K extends keyof RootObject>(key: K) {
  let  prop = this._has(key) ? this.user[key] : null;

  if (key == this.last) { 
    return prop;
  }

  if (typeof prop == 'object') {
    let k = Object.keys(prop)[0] as K;
    this.user = prop;
    return this.prop(k);
  }

  }

  private _has(prop: string): boolean {
    return this.user.hasOwnProperty(prop);
  }

  public propString(properties: string) { 
    this.last = properties.split('.').slice(-1).pop();
  }

}

let b = {
  'organization': {
    'name': 'Oleg'
  }
};

let a = new A();
a.user = b;
a.propString('organization.name');
let d = a.prop('organization');
console.log(d);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you're looking for, since you left out a bunch of your class implementation.  I will give you a more general possible solution to what you're trying to achieve:

```
type WrapIfObject<T> = T extends object ? ObjectWrapper<T> : T; 
class ObjectWrapper<T> {
  constructor(public object: T) { }
  prop<K extends keyof T>(k: K): WrapIfObject<T[K]>;
  prop<K extends keyof T>(k: K): T[K] | ObjectWrapper<T[K]> {
    const val = this.object[k];
    return (typeof val === "object") ? new ObjectWrapper(val) : val;
  }
}
```

The above is a class named `ObjectWrapper`, which wraps an object you pass in the constructor.  When you call the `prop()` method with one of the object's keys, the return value will either be the property value if it is *not* an object, or an `ObjectWrapper` which wraps the property value.  It is in this way that you can chain calls to `prop()` until you get to a non-object value.  Note that the return type of `prop()`, `WrapIfObject<T[K]>`, is a [conditional type](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#conditional-types) instead of a union, which lets the compiler strongly type the output in a way that makes it easier to use.

Let's see how it works:

```
const val = {a: {b: "hey"}, c: "you"};
const valWrap = new ObjectWrapper(val);
console.log(valWrap.prop("a").prop("b").charAt(0)); // "h"
console.log(valWrap.prop("c").charAt(0)); // "y"
```

The above type-checks with no errors; TypeScript knows that `valWrap.prop("a").prop("b")` is a `string` and that `valWrap.prop("c")` is a `string`.  It will complain if you do the wrong thing:

```
const oops = valWrap.prop("a").charAt(0); // error!
// Property 'charAt' does not exist on type 'ObjectWrapper<{ b: string; }>'.
```

And thanks to the [distributive](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#distributive-conditional-types) property of conditional types, it will produce unions in the right places:

```
const x = new ObjectWrapper({a: Math.random() < 0.5 ? "string" : {b: 3}});
const y = x.prop("a") ; // string | ObjectWrapper<{b: number}>
const z = (typeof y === "string") ? y.length : y.prop("b"); // number
console.log(z); // 6 or 3
```

Note how `y` is known to be *either* a `string` *or* an `ObjectWrapper<{b: number}>`.

Anyway, hope you can use that to give you an idea how to solve your issue.  Good luck!

Comment: Can you see my update, I tried to suggest one approach

Comment: From my glance at that code I’d say it looks brittle and ill-typed.  TypeScript doesn’t support mutating types, so if the type of the result of `a.prop("organization")` depends on the state of `a`, you will have a bad time.  I recommend returning new objects instead of mutating the existing object, as in `ObjectWrapper` above.